# Line for set of three-dimensional vectors

Tags: calculus, matrices, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors

If there is a set for 3D vectors $v$ where
$ v \times \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -27 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix}$
is a line, what is this line's equation?

I'm not sure how to solve this, except for setting $v = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$ and maybe having a linear system of equations, but I don't see how I could use that to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\vec{v}=\langle a, b, c\rangle, \;\; \vec{u}=\langle-1, 1, 4\rangle,\;\;\vec{w}=\langle5, -27, 8\rangle$.

Then $\vec{v}\times\vec{u}=\langle b-c, -4a-c, a+b\rangle,$

so $\vec{v}\times\vec{u}=\vec{w}\iff 4b-c=5,\; -4a-c=-27,\; a+b=8\iff c=4b-5 \text{  and  } a=8-b$,

so $\vec{v}=\langle8-b, b, 4b-5\rangle=\langle8,0,-5\rangle+b\langle-1, 1, 4\rangle$.

Therefore the line has parametric equations $\color{red}{x=8-t, \; y=t, \;z=4t-5}$.

---

$\textbf{Alternate solution}$:

With the same notation as above, let $\vec{z}=\vec{u}\times\vec{w}=\langle116, 28, 22\rangle$.

Then $\vec{z}\times\vec{u}=(\vec{u}\times\vec{w})\times\vec{u}=(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u})\vec{w}-(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{w})\vec{u}=18\vec{w}$ since $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=18$ and $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{w}=0$.

Then if $\vec{s}=\frac{1}{18}\vec{z}=\langle\frac{58}{9}, \frac{14}{9}, \frac{11}{9}\rangle\;$ and $\;\color{red}{\vec{r}=\vec{s}+t\vec{u}=\langle\frac{58}{9}-t, \frac{14}{9}+t, \frac{11}{9}+4t\rangle}$,

$\hspace{.3 in}\vec{r}\times\vec{u}=(\vec{s}+t\vec{u})\times\vec{u}=\vec{s}\times\vec{u}+t(\vec{u}\times\vec{u})=\vec{w}+t\vec{0}=\vec{w}.$

Answer (score 1):

It certainly comes down to solving a system of linear equations

You need the cross product formula here, for which a determinant form exists.
Information about that can be found here:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx

So if you call your vector $v=<a,b,c>$ Then all you need to do is to set up the determinant with the first row $x,y,z$, the second row $a,b,c$ and the third row $-1,1,4$
Working out the determinant results in:
$x(4b-c)-y(4a+c)+z(a+b)$. Bring the negative in front of the $y$ inside to obtain the following equations:
$4b-c=5$ , $-4a-c=-27$ and $a+b=8$ Can you solve these equations? Now how about that line? Remember that the zero vector technically also work so a parametric equation of this "line" can thus be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\i}{\hat{\mathbf{i}}}
\newcommand{\j}{\hat{\mathbf{j}}}
\newcommand{\k}{\hat{\mathbf{k}}}
\newcommand{\v}{\vec{\mathbf{v}}}
$
Let $v =  \v$ and 
$$
\v = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix},
\quad 
\i = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad 
\j = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix},
\quad 
\k = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
v \times \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -27 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}
$$
can be rewritten as 
$$
\v \times \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} 
\times 
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -27 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Let us expand vector product:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\v \times \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{vmatrix} 
\i & \j & \k \\
a & b & c \\
-1 & 1 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix} b & c \\ 1 & 4 \end{vmatrix} \i-
\begin{vmatrix} a & c \\ -1 & 4 \end{vmatrix} \j+
\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \k
=
\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -27 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, we conclude 
$$
\begin{cases}
4 b - c = 5 \\ 
4 a + c = 27 \\
a + b = 8
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
4 b - c = 5 \\ 
4 a + 4b = 32 \\
a  = 8 - b
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
4 b - c = 5 \\ 
32 + 8b = 32 \\
a  = 8 - b
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
c = -5 \\ 
b = 0 \\
a  = 8
\end{cases}
$$
Finally, we write 
$$
\bbox[9px, border:3px solid #FF0000]{v =   \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 0 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}}
$$

Comment: Just checking, I thought the last equation is $a+b=8$  the entries in that sub determinant are $a,b,-1,1$ Or am I incorrect?

Comment: @imranfat You are correct, I had a typo.  I was lucky in a sense that this typo does not interfere with the final answer, since $b=0$. Thank you for pointing it out though.

Comment: @Vlad: Would that mean the line is $r = v+ 0t$, where 0 is the zero vector and r stands for the line in general?

Comment: @MathyPerson. No, the parameter $t$ goes with the $v$. It is the 3D line that passes through the Origin and has a directional vector $v$. In other words: All (fractional) multiples of vector $v$ are solutions. I think you could accept Vlad's answer...

Comment: @imranfat Doesn't Vlad's answer show that the solution is a single vector, and not a line?

Comment: @user84413 It is a line, because any scalar multiple of this vector is also a solution. In other words, any multiple vector is perpendicular to the 2 given vectors

Comment: @imranfat I'm not sure I understand why -- for example, I don't think $w=2v=\langle 16, 0, -10\rangle$ is a solution, since $w\times\langle-1,1,4\rangle=\langle10,-54,16\rangle$.

Comment: @imranfat I agree with user84413. The solution of the equation in problem statement is indeed a single vector, not a line. I believe that the original question "find the line" is a bit sloppy, since we are given a cross product equation, not just orthogonality constraint. The definition of the cross product relies on both directions and magnitudes of two vectors, therefore we cannot rescale only one of them without amending cross product equation. I think that solution vector $\vec v$ is intended to be used in order to write an equation of the line, although it is not spelled out explicitly.

Comment: @MathyPerson As we found $\vec v$, we can write the equation of the line as $\vec r = a +t\,\vec v$, where $t\in \Bbb R$ is a parameter and $a\in \Bbb R^3$ is a point your line goes through. Your problem statement says nothing about what $a$ should be, we can only speculate on what we have. I think it might be reasonable to assume $a = 0$  since in the vector product equation we use regular vectors, whose initial point is usually assumed to  be the origin.

Comment: @MathyPerson In fact, if we choose to be completely pedantic, the first sentence in you problem statement says  "$\, \vec v \times \left( \begin{smallmatrix}-1\\1\\4\end{smallmatrix} \right) = \left( \begin{smallmatrix}5\\-27\\8\end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is a line". In particular, it states that the __vector__ $\left( \begin{smallmatrix}5\\-27\\8\end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is a __line__, which is a contradiction. May I ask you about the source of the problem?

Comment: @user84413 Yes, With respect to the Cross product, there is only one solution. I thought that the cross product was a set up to find all vectors perpendicular to the given 2 vectors....

Comment: @imranfat You were right that the solution is a line, and not just one vector.